# Jump to cell in selected column and row containing value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro to jump to a cell in Excel, where I would select a specific column by highlighting it, and then jump to the row containing a searched value from different column.  I know how to make the macro and shortcut, it is just the vba code I am struggling with.  I found this macro just need to know how to change it so it jumps to the row containing a searched value in a specific column, and not the row number of the input.

```
Sub JumpTo()
'Description: Select the specified row or column
  'If row is specified, active column is used
  'If column is specified, active row is used
'Source: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/jump-to-row-column-keyboard-shortcut

Dim sResult As String

  On Error Resume Next 'Blanket error handling
  
  'Display inputbox to prompt user for row/column
  sResult = InputBox("Type a row number or column letter and press Enter.", "Jump To...")
  
  If IsNumeric(sResult) Then 'Select row
    Cells(sResult, ActiveCell.Column).Select
  Else 'Select column
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, sResult).Select
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `Application.Match` or `Range.Find`.

Comment: The code as written returns the Numeric row# and not the row of an inputted value in a specific column. In my case I want to return the row of a value in column "A"

Answer (score 0):

**Several hints** *(in addition to comments in code example)*

- Use `Option Explicit` to force **type declarations** and try to be explicit.
  Example: `Dim r As Variant` though an implicit `Dim r` would be sufficient.
- **Fully qualify** your *sheet reference(s)*. Example: `Cells` alone
  would refer to *any* currently active sheet which needn't be the one you have focus to.
  Prefix e.g. by `ws.Cells(r, "A")...` or use a point prefix within a `With ws` - `End With` structure.
- Declare the accurate **sheet type** specifically.
  Example: As you are referring to worksheets, don't code `Dim ws As Sheet` including shapes, too.
  Narrow the field via `Dim ws As Worksheet`.
- Refer to the wanted sheet either via its tabular **sheet name** like e.g.
  `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` or the **project's sheet Code(Name)** as indicated in VB
  Editor's properties window, e.g. `Set ws = Sheet1` as variable name (without quotes).
- Avoid `On Error Resume Next` without specific error handling and exact knowledge about what you are doing.
  You will find numerous examples at SO.
- As a general rule avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` whereever possible, if not wanted or needed expressly (like in this example).
  *See [How to avoid using select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)*.

**Code example**

- ad 1+2) Note that `InputBox` (contrary to `Application.InputBox`) returns string results only.
  So this simple example code assumes string values or numeric string inputs which would be changed to doubles to allow findings.
- ad 3) Only *one* way to find matching values (case insensitively) is by `Application.Match`. *Alternatively you could apply a `Range.Find` as proposed in comment or loop through a 2-dim datafield array one by one etc.*
- The `Application.Match` approach (which doesn't pretend to be the best one) has the bonus to allow an easy *positive* check for *valid* row results via `IsNumeric` detecting/ignoring
  `Error 2042` values (to prevent eventual errors when trying to use an error results) ...
  Alternatively you could check negatively via `If Not IsError(r) Then`.

```
Option Explicit                                 ' Module head: Force type declarations
Sub JumpTo()
'0) Fully qualify sheet reference
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  ' << change to your needs

'1) Display inputbox to prompt user for value input
    Dim srch As Variant                          ' provide for possible change to double   
    srch = InputBox("Type a value to be searched in column A and press Enter.", "Jump To...")
'2) Change numeric search string to double
    If IsNumeric(srch) Then srch = CDbl(srch)    
'3) Get row number of search value and go to found cell
    With ws                                      ' refer to worksheet object ws
        'a) Execute Match                        ' case independant
        Dim r As Variant                         ' needs Variant for IsNumeric check!
        r = Application.Match(srch, .Columns("A"), 0)
        'b) Check if Match returns a valid row number
        If IsNumeric(r) Then                     ' ignores error 2042 if not found
            .Cells(r, "A").Select                ' or: .Cells(r, 1).Select
        Else
            MsgBox "Value " & srch & " not found!", vbExclamation, "Error 2042"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```